# How to drop an item in a jquery-ui sortable list inside another item in that list

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list using jquery-ui:

```
<div id="sortable">
  <div class="ui-state-default">Item 1</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">Item 2</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">Item 3</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">Item 4</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">Item 5</div>
</div>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true
    });
  } );
 </script>
```

In some cases I want to be able to drop an item in sortable list into another one. For instance, when I drag `Item 1` and drop it right over `Item 3` it be inserted inside `Item 3` not become a sibling div before or after it.

I couldn't find anything in jquery-ui documentation, in fact I need to get the item I'm over it when I'm dragging another item.

Comment: To confirm, you want to make items droppable, such that when dropped, the item become a child of the item instead of being sorted as a sibling? This is not a feature of sortable by default. You'll need to create hierarchy (Building a new list container) upon drop or update.

Answer (score 2):

Created the following from the basic examples for Sortable. This example has child elements to be used as sub-lists to each list item.

```js
$(function() {
  function resize(t, c) {
    var h = (c * 18) + 9;
    var p = (c * 1.2) + 0.6;
    t.css("height", "calc(" + h + "px + " + p + "em)");
  }
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: ".child-list",
    handle: ".ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s",
    items: "> div.ui-state-default"
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
  $(".child-list").sortable({
    connectWith: ".parent-list",
    receive: function(e, ui) {
      var numItems = $(".ui-state-default", this).length;
      resize($(this).closest(".ui-state-default"), numItems);
    },
    remove: function(e, ui) {
      var numItems = $(".ui-state-default", this).length;
      resize($(this).closest(".ui-state-default"), numItems);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#sortable {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 340px;
}

#sortable>div {
  margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  height: 18px;
}

#sortable>div>span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.3em;
}

#sortable .child-list {
  display: block;
  width: calc(340px - 2em);
  min-height: 1em;
}

#sortable .child-list>div {
  background: #999;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.ui-state-highlight {
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="sortable" class="parent-list">
  <div class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span> Item 1
    <div class="child-list">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span> Item 2
    <div class="child-list">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span> Item 3
    <div class="child-list">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span> Item 4
    <div class="child-list">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span> Item 5
    <div class="child-list">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using the `receive` and `remove` callbacks for the child sortable, the list item can be resized to accept the item. It may not be the best example as the placeholder for the sub-list doesn't really show properly. You're welcome to improve it if it fits your needs.

Hope that helps.